# Submit form when enter is pressed using jQuery submit()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a handler to catch the event of an "enter" inside a set of inputs in the context of an authentication function, but it's not working when I press the key. The code is as follows :

```
$('#login form').submit(function(e) { login(e); });

function login(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();

    var l = $('#logo a').attr('href');
    var name = $('#login input[name="login_username"]').val();
    var pass = $('#login input[name="login_password"]').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: l+'user/login',
        data: 'username='+name+'&password='+pass,
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response)
        {
            if (response.status == true)
                window.location = response.redirect;
            else
                jQuery.facebox('<p class="facebox-notice">'+response.error+'</p>');
        }
    });
}
```

It does work, however, to the button I have for the same purpose :

```
$('#dologin').click(function(e) { login(e); });
```

Any ideas why? Cheers!

**EDIT**

The markup is as follows :

```
<div id="login">
  <form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="login_username" />
    <input type="password" name="login_password" />
    <a href="" id="dologin">LOGIN</a>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: could you show some html as well?

Comment: What is your HTML? Could it be that your form has ID `#login`? Where do you attach the key handler to? What does it do? Please add this part too. What do you mean by *not working*? `login` is not called?

Comment: And post the non working source on jsfiddle.net if possible?

Comment: As an aside, you can just do `$('#login form').submit(login);`, it'll get the same parameters as any anonymous function, so you'll get the event you want, same goes for `.click(login)`.

Comment: Why don't you have a normal `<input type="submit">` button? Users with JS disabled won't be able to use your site. *(still missing how you attach the key event handler and what it does)*

Comment: @Felix Kling: No I don't, and the website itself would become meaningless without javascript, so I found no reason to include it anyway.

Comment: @yoda: Well, if you use a `submit` button, you get the `enter` handling for free: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/kaf66/

Comment: @Felix Kling: Thanks for the tip! Aparently if I put the submit button inside the form, despite having no jQuery handler at all, the enter key works just fine .. Mistery solved apparently. Please answer above so that I can accept the answer and help others in the near future with the same issue. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So your goal is to submit the form when <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed, correct?

The easiest way to achieve this is to use a submit button

```
<input type="submit" value="Login" />
```

instead of the link. Then the event is handled by the browser.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/kaf66/)

If you prefer to have a link because of the *style*, you can use CSS to style the button and [make it look like a link](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/9j5yb/9/).

Comment: if i want to submit by this method why i need javascript

Answer (score 1):

**updated**

What you need is to have an `<input type=submit>`. However you can choose to hide it off screen. That way you get the submition on `enter` for free.

Keep in mind though you can't hide the submit with `display:none` of changing visibility because it then becomes an inactive element, and won't work on most browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Try to include a **hidden** submit button in your form.

**updated**
Okay, that would work in Firefox, but not in Chrome. IE, I suppose, won't handle it too.

Well, you can go script way http://jsfiddle.net/GqHzZ/. Add a keypress handler on all event fields that would trigger the submit function, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#login form input').keypress(function(e) { if(e.which == '13')login(e); });
```

Answer (score 1):

With webkit based browsers (Chrome, Safari) I've found that trying to do certain "on click" events, submits and other things with a blank href element in your anchor tag won't work.

```
<a href="" id="dologin">LOGIN</a>
```

The reason is simply that your href is blank.

If you set it as pretty much anything, for example **#** and **return false** in your jQuery ... webkit will work just like Firefox, and other browsers.

The **return false** part, btw ... prevents the "[default action](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)" which would be to "follow" the # link.

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" id="submitbutton">LOGIN</a>
```

**jQuery**

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submitbutton').click(function() {
        $('#someForm').submit();
        return false;
    }); 
 });
</script>
```

This is even more strictly enforced (it seems) on mobile webkit, i.e. iPhone, iPad, Android.